# mysql_fetch_array is including previous value in next one

Tags: php

I used this same code before and not like that just for one image at one time it is working fine there for showing img(stars)but now stars in first value is fine next it is collecting result with previous one

```
while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($tableone))
{
    $Rating = $query['rating'];
    $totalV = $query['total_votes'];
    $commentcount = $query['comment_counts'];




            if (!$Rating == 0 )
        {

                        $number = $Rating / $totalV ;
                        $numbers = (round($number,3));  
                        for ($x = 1 ; $x <= $numbers ; $x++)
                       {

                        $star .= '<img src="img/stars.gif" width="14%"/>';

                        }

                        $left = 5 - $numbers ;

                        for ($x = 1 ; $x <= $left ; $x++)

                        {

                           $result .='<img src="img/whitestar.gif" width="12%"/>';

                          }

                           if ( strpos($left, '.' ) == true)
                            {

                            $hs .= '<img src="img/halfwhitestar.gif" width="12%"/>';

                            }

                            $result1 = $star. $hs .$result;


                }
                else 
                {
                $result1 ='Null';
                }


                if (empty($totalV))
                {
                $totalV = 'No votes';
                    }

                $totalV ="/".$totalV;


                $ratingbox = "<span id=\"ratingimg\">".$result1." </span>

                <br/>

                <span class=\"valueimg\">".$number.$totalV."</span>";

}
```

my Values in database of each image is

[image: rating and total votes in database]

and this code is visible like this

[image: rating par Image it is including previous values as well in next]

this code i am using now for table for all images present in database including their some information...need guidance:S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are concatenating strings during your loop, those strings just keep growing with each iteration of the loop.

I suggest that you reset these variables to blank strings upon each iteration of your `while` loop: `$star`, `$hs`, `$result`.

Something like this:

```
while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($tableone)) {

    $star=$hs=$result='';

    ...
```